# Menu not sliding with use of toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am try to get a menu to slide to the left on click of a button and then slide back to its original position on click of the same button.  I am using toggle, but I can not seem to get it to work.  The button would also slide to the right so it is visible when the menu is not.  Without the toggle method the menu and button slide correctly, but do not slide back.

**JQuery:**

```
$("#menu-button").click(function() {
    $("#menu-button").toggle(function() {
        $("#menu").animate({
            "left": "-=300px"
        }, "slow");
        $("#menu-button").animate({
            "right": "-=60px"
        }, "slow");

    },

    function() {

        $("#menu").animate({
            "left": "+=300px"
        }, "slow");
        $("#menu-button").animate({
            "right": "-=60px"
        }, "slow");

    }
});
```

});

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menu">
<button id="menu-button">press</button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu {

  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

#menu-button {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor:pointer; 
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using? according to the [.toggle() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) it hides the element it is called on. so even it would move back, it won't be visible. ([Jsfiffle](https://jsfiddle.net/hs3eu7pj/4/) of your code with the newest jQuery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of toggle, I find it easiest, possibly years later, to review code that is explicit. Personal preference is to use a var to store current div state. *Personal preference . . . but it works.*

```js
var menuOut = true;
$("#menu-button").click(function() {
  if (menuOut){
      menuOut = false;
      $("#menu").animate({
        "left": "-300px"
      }, "slow");
      $("#menu-button").animate({
        "left": "60px"
      }, "slow");
  }else{
      menuOut = true;
      $("#menu").animate({
        "left": 0
      }, "slow");
      $("#menu-button").animate({
        "left": 0
      }, "slow");
  }
});
```

```css
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: darkcyan;
}
#menu-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menu">
<button id="menu-button">press</button>
</div>
```